# How to set the value of TextInput on button click in FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to increment the value and set it to TextInput onclick. But there are many TextInputs and buttons, created dynamically with each item in FlatList.

```
<FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()} data={allGroceryItems} renderItem={itemData => (

                            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', }}>

//id in item.id is an object in array & addQty(id) is just an empty function for now

                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnCount} onPress={() => addQty(itemData.item.id)}> 
                                    <Text style={{fontFamily: 'open-sans-reg', fontSize: 16}}>+</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                                <TextInput keyboardType="numeric" placeholder="0" style={styles.txtCount}/> // this is the TextInput 

                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnCount} onPress={() => deleteQty(itemData.item.id)}>
                                    <Text style={{fontFamily: 'open-sans-reg', fontSize: 22}}>-</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>

                    )}
                    />
```

So, basically its a counter. When `+` button is pressed, it increments the number and set to the clicked index's TextInput value. When `-` button is pressed, it decrements the number and set to the clicked index's TextInput value.

How to get the clicked button's TextInput and set the value of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out by adding a hook state.

Solution:

```
    const [txtValue, setTxtValue] = useState([]);

const addQty = (id) => {
    const dataArr = [...txtValue];
    var prev = `${dataArr[id]}` == 'undefined' ? 0 : dataArr[id];
    dataArr[id] = prev + 1;
    setTxtValue(dataArr);
}

const deleteQty = (id) => {
    const dataArr = [...txtValue];
    var prev = `${dataArr[id]}` == 'undefined' ? 0 : dataArr[id];
    if(prev == 0){
        dataArr[id] = prev;
    }else{
        dataArr[id] = prev - 1;
    }
    setTxtValue(dataArr);
}

<FlatList keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()} data={allGroceryItems} renderItem={itemData => (

                        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', }}>//id in item.id is an object in array

                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnCount} onPress={() => addQty(itemData.item.id)}> 
                                <Text style={{fontFamily: 'open-sans-reg', fontSize: 16}}>+</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            <TextInput value={`${txtValue[itemData.item.id]}`=== "undefined" ? '0' : `${txtValue[itemData.item.id]}`} keyboardType="numeric" placeholder="0" style={styles.txtCount}/> // this is the TextInput 

                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnCount} onPress={() => deleteQty(itemData.item.id)}>
                                <Text style={{fontFamily: 'open-sans-reg', fontSize: 22}}>-</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>

                )}
                />
```